# Why does the PMOS burn out in a buck boost converter when I increase the power supply voltage?

Tags: voltage, mosfet, current, converter, pulse

My MOSFET warms up and even burns out when I change the power supply
to 8V.  I get an input current of 1A , and the MOSFET burns.

This is the [datasheet.](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/68328/IRF/IRF9540N.html)

I dont know why.  I have an IRF9540n MOSFET.

This is my schematic:

[image: buck boost converter]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the schematic, you are driving the gate with 3.3V and GND. Since it is a PMOS, it must be driven with VIN to turn it off, and GND to turn it on. At least Vgs should be larger than 3.3V to turn it on properly, perhaps even 6V based on the gate charge curves.

Answer (score 1):

At 6V input voltage, the FET is switched off at 3.3V control.
[image: fet1]

At 8V input voltage, it cannot be switched off at 3.3V. So even without control, a current of 2.5A flows into the inductance:

[image: fet2]

The control must be changed so that when switched off, the Gate voltage will the same as the input voltage.

Comment: i cant change the control i am controlling with raspberry pi this is my project

Comment: @hos well then your project is impossible, good luck! (but seriously it's not impossible, you ***can*** change it, you just need some more parts in order to make an 8V signal out of a 3.3V signal...)

Comment: @hos The simplest method is a [transistor](https://imgur.com/a/jFID8Ah), but you need to invert the control signal. The delay of the transistor changes the duty cycle, so the correct solution for this frequency would be a gate drive IC. You can also simulate this by modifying your own schematic in LTSpice.

Answer (score 0):

as other answers have noted, you are not driving the gate at the correct voltage levels. You need a gate driver , the MCP14A0452 would be suitable for your application. [image: MCP14A0452 datasheet snip]

There are many others to pick from , just search "gate driver" , you need one with

- approx 1.5v input threshold
- a max Vss greater than 8v (that would be almost all of them)
- non-inverting to match what you have , or inverting if you want Rpi output=high to turn on MOSFET.
- at least 1A peak output current
- you don't really need UVLO (undervoltage lockout)

Bonus: If you connect a zener between the output voltage on C1 , and the threshold pin of the gate driver, then the gate driver will shutoff if your output voltage exceeds (zener_voltage - 1.5v)

Also: Given you don't understand how MOSFETS are meant to be driven, do you have the correct type of inductor for L1? and do you have the correct PWM frequency out of your Rpi to get the required ON and OFF times, so the inductor can be run at the desired current levels without saturating. You can't just pick any random 100uH inductor. Maybe head over to the Coilcraft website, and poke around over there.